# Changes made to app.js is not applying in react js

Tags: reactjs

I'm totally new to react !

**Problem**

I've installed `create-react-app` globally, and then created a react app in a folder, and started the development server. When I type `localhost:3000` it loads the main page but when I try to make changes to `app.js` file and they are not reflecting in the browser, why is this so ?
I'm using  the following command to run the server :

`npm run start`

I guess the server starts fine, as it gives me this after running `npm run start`:

`newapp@0.1.0 start F:\Projects\newapp`

> react-scripts start
>   `

I want to know why my changes that I may gonna make are not reflecting in the browser ?

Console is showing this:

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDDMr.png)

Comment: is there any error  on console?

Comment: Yeah , there is an error I've updated the post !, @Mahmoud-abdelslam

Comment: Could you please share the code . There is an online tool you can share it on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Well , I was using git bash , then I tried in windows built in cmd, so when I run `npm start` it gave me > do you want to run the server on the another port? I said yes, and then it worked perfectly fine, @Mahmoud-abdelslam

Comment: Great ! . if you are using visual studio code you can access the terminal from view>Terminal , it will open windows powershell that you can use it to run your application .

Comment: No, I'm using sublime text, I know the about the embedded terminal in VSCode, but I don't use that, I'm on sublime, by the thanks for all help !

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you first of all remove `node_modules` and run `npm run install` again.

Then you should make sure that the folder where your project is is not inside a dropbox folder or any other kind of special folder.

Make sure, so we can rule out any other problem, to use the project provided by `create-react-app` as is, no changes yet (not even renaming of files)

Try to run the app from within the folder, instead of from outside. (`cd F:\Projects\myapp` and then `npm run start`)

For testing, use a simple text editor to modify the contents of the file.

If nothing works, check https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/troubleshooting#npm-start-doesnt-detect-changes

And ultimately if nothing of that works as well, you should comment here or open a new issue https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/659

Comment: my error was very fool, im starting command to run yarn start in another packages :(